# java inherit method of Nester Inner class where Inner class has private Identifier

Tags: java, inheritance

```
public class Testing {

  public String name = null;

  public String getName() {
    TestingInner test = new TestingInner("Testing inner override");
    return test.getNameString();
  }

  public String testName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  private class TestingInner {

    String nameString = null;

    public TestingInner(String name) {
      this.nameString = name;
    }

    public String getNameString() {
      return "Inner Class " + this.nameString;
    }
  }
}

public class Testing2 extends Testing.TestingInner {

  @Override
  public String getNameString() {
    System.out.println("Override Inner class method");
    return "This is";
  }
}
```

Getting multiple error message which is expected

> The method getNameString() of type Testing2 must override or implement a supertype method
>
> The type Testing.TestingInner is not visible

**Question** is there any way to override getNameString() which is under inner class which is private.
Changing private to public will work, but wanted to see if any implementation exist to override getNameString()

Comment: On the JVM level, there are no private classes - only package private classes. While you have a hard time compiling the code (for example by removing the `private` modifier from `TestingInner`), the generated class should work at runtime.

Comment: Why are you trying to extend a private class? The point of `private` is to keep it invisible outside the declaring class.

Comment: @shmosel Why are you questioning OPs curiosity? The point of SO is to get answers to questions.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I'm trying to understand the question. Is OP unaware of what `private` means, or trying to work around it, or trying to do something else entirely?

Comment: @shmosel "Changing private to public will work, but wanted to see if any implementation exist to override getNameString()". My educated guess after reading especially the quoted part of the question is: Yes, OP knows/is aware what `private` means.

Comment: So, if you declare the inner-class as _static_, even if it is _private_, you can then extend another class from it ... .

Comment: @Reilas the extendability of a class has nothing to do with whether it is static or not. In terms of this question, it is purely a question of its accessibility.

Comment: @AndyTurner, then, how is it working on my computer?  Should I recommend this as a solution?

Comment: What part of, _"... Question is there any way to override getNameString() which is under inner class which is private ..."_, am I misunderstanding.  I got it to work here.

Comment: @Reilas I cannot say why it works for you, because I don't know exactly how you've declared the class. Perhaps you've declared `Testing2` inside `Testing`? It would help if you provided a [mcve], e.g. on ideone. Anyway,  you previously wrote this as an answer, and it got downvoted through the floor; I'm not sure that suggesting the same thing again would get a different response.

Comment: @AndyTurner, then why are you not recommending that as a solution?  If, it is a solution.

Comment: @Reilas I do. It's the last paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to be able to extend a class, the class must be accessible: referring to [JLS 8.1.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4):

> ```
> ClassExtends:
>    extends ClassType
> ```
>
> ...
>
> **The ClassType must name an accessible class (§6.6), or a compile-time error occurs.**

Referring to [JLS 6.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1), "Determining Accessibility" (emphasis added):

> ...
>
> - Otherwise, the member [class, interface, field, or method] or constructor is declared private. Access is permitted only when one of the following is true:
>
>   - **Access occurs from within the body of the top level class or interface that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor.**
>   - Access occurs in the permits clause of the top level class or interface that encloses the declaration of the member.
>   - Access occurs in the record component list of the top level record class that encloses the declaration of the member.

Your class would be accessible inside the body of `Testing`, the top-level class, so you could extend it there. But you can't do it outside the body of `Testing`.

Comment: A much better answer than mine +1.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do it.  You can't extend a class that isn't visible so there is nothing visible to override.  That it is an inner class is irrelevant.